# How do I get Flutter packages to download?

Tags: flutter

I am starting a new project in Flutter using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). I create a new project and get the general framework for the project.

I try to add a package.
Here is my *.yaml* file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.5
```

When I run `flutter pub get`, it gives me this:

```
[client_miner] flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.5.

Because client_miner depends on flutter_icons >=0.0.2 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
exit code 1
```

First of all, I don't know where I am getting flutter_icons >=0.0.2
Second, I get errors on the import package code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
This is the error:
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:provider/provider.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `flutter pub add package_name` command to add the package.

For example:

```
flutter pub add provider
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Visual Studio Code, you can simply enter the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then in the search bar search for Dart: Add Dependency, after that you can search for your package. It will do all the work for you from add package in [pubspec.yaml](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec) and run command `flutter pub add [package name]`.